# Get 'purchasable' from ElementAPI

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-elementapi

The [elementApi](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api/tree/v1#elementtype-required) docs state you can use custom elementTypes via plugins.  I am using craft commerce which states it creates the custom elementType '[purchasable](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/purchasables)'

I've tried:

```
return [
'endpoints' => [
    'category.json' => [
        'elementType' => 'purchasable',
        'criteria' => [
            // 'category' => 'products', // randomly trying stuff here!
            // 'section' => 'products',
            // 'type' => 'products',
        ],
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            return [
                'title' => $entry->title,
                'url' => $entry->url,
            ];
        },
    ]
]]
```

I've tried many variations on the word purchasable, as we as random guesses like 'product', 'item' etc etc

I should mention I am able to JSON back with all categories, Entries etc etc

I am sure this is possible, as craft, craftcommerce and elementApi are all made by the same guys!

Any help would be amazing

Comment: What's the class name of your purchasable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
return [
'endpoints' => [
    'products.json' => [
        'elementType' => 'Commerce_Product',
        'criteria' => [
            // 'category' => 'products', // randomly trying stuff here!
            // 'section' => 'products',
            // 'type' => 'products',
        ],
        'transformer' => function(Commerce_ProductModel $product) {
            return [
                'title' => $product->title,
                'url' => $product->url,
            ];
        },
    ]
]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's giving me the classic: No element type exists by the type “Commerce_Products”.

Comment: Ah! drop the 's' ! : Commerce_Product

thank you!

Comment: If you are using Commerce 2, the `Commerce_Product` should be `Product` and add a `use craft\commerce\elements\Product` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

For Commerce 2

```
use craft\commerce\elements\Product;
return [
    'endpoints' => [
    'products.json' => [
        'elementType' => Product::class,
        'transformer' => function(Product $product) {
            return [
                'title' => $product->title,
                'url' => $product->url,
            ];
        },
    ],
    ]
];
```